# How to explicitly acknowledge or deacknowledge messages with Qpid Proton Python

Tags: python, amqp, qpid, qpid-proton

I have a Qpid Proton Python `MessageHandler` receiving some messages which trigger some processing. How can I reject a message in case the processing fails? As far as [I can tell from the API documentation](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.33.0/proton/python/docs/proton.handlers.html?highlight=auto#proton.handlers.MessagingHandler), the default is `auto_accept=True`. However, changing this to `False` doesn't seem to avoid acknowledging messages as a subsequent receiver doesn't catch up with the failing message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable auto accept, explicitly accepting or rejecting a message is your responsibility.  If you do neither, the message is stuck in limbo.

Here's an example of application code that does explicit acks:

```
def on_message(self, event):
    try:
        process_message(event.message)
        event.delivery.update(ACCEPTED)
    except:
        event.delivery.update(REJECTED)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference to self.accept(event.delivery)?

Comment: Not really.  They achieve the same thing.